# Format of float to QString conversion

Tags: c++, qt, format, qstring

I would like to convert a float to a QString but replacing the `.` by a `,`.

For example, I want the float `12.95` to be converted to a QString that looks like `12,95`.

I guess I can do it with something like:

```
QString().sprintf("%something", myFloat);
```

But how should I write instead of `%something`?

Maybe I can do it like this: `QString::number(myFloat, 'f').replace(".", ",")` but it is not very pretty...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you try [QLocale::toString()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlocale.html#toString-14) already?

The following code should return the float with comma as decimal separator:

```
QLocale german(QLocale::German, QLocale::Germany);
QString s1 = german.toString(12.95, 'f');
```